# Read pixels from mipmapped texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, directx

is it possible to to read specific area of the texture from specific mipmap level to buffer? I'm looking for a method to save texture into a PNG/JPG file. Each file should represent each mipmap level. Why? Because I'm loading specific file depending on level of detail quadtree (to much complicate to explain but it's necessarily to not use whole GPU memory but only a few mb). Is it possible to do that using PBOs? I need a function like glTexSubImage2D (which allows to choose x, y, width, height and mipmap level) to read pixels from texture to buffer.

Comment: If you want to transfer pixels to the cpu, you can use glGetTexImage (you can only copy the whole mipmap though). Im not aware of any function that can copy pixels to a gpu buffer. However,  you can use texelFetch in glsl to copy pixels manually in a compute shader

Comment: "Im not aware of any function that can copy pixels to a gpu buffe"

glTexSubimage

Comment: Oh, I forgot about GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER